# Schema specified is not valid - error in asp.net application after upgrade Oracle database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, iis

I have an asp.net web application which uses only SQL Database on Windows SQL Server 2008. When Oracle client was upgraded (I didn't do this), something has changed. I saw that in IIS in "String Connections" appeared additional empty connection - *OraAspNetConString* and I'm start getting errors on these pages of my app, where should be displayed information from SQL Database.

I don't know where should I start repairing, because I'm not using Oracle database, but errors are connected with this. I don't want to change app code also, because I'm using deploying version. So maybe do you have any ideas?

There is an error below which I'm getting:

> Server Error in '/Budzet' Application.
>
> Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   Oracle.DataAccess.src.EntityFramework.Resources.EFOracleStoreSchemaDefinition.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
>   Models.Model_Excel.ssdl(2,49) : error 0172: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The Provider 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' is different from 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' that was encountered earlier.
>   Models.Model_Excel.ssdl(2,82) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2008' is different from '9.2' that was encountered earlier.
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>   Oracle.DataAccess.src.EntityFramework.Resources.EFOracleStoreSchemaDefinition.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
>   Models.Model_Excel.ssdl(2,49) : error 0172: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The Provider 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' is different from 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' that was encountered earlier.
>   Models.Model_Excel.ssdl(2,82) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2008' is different from '9.2' that was encountered earlier.
>
> **Source Error:**
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**

```
[MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
Oracle.DataAccess.src.EntityFramework.Resources.EFOracleStoreSchemaDefinition.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
Models.Model_Excel.ssdl(2,49) : error 0172: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The Provider 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' is different from 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client' that was encountered earlier.
Models.Model_Excel.ssdl(2,82) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2008' is different from '9.2' that was encountered earlier.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors() +44
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths) +180
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver) +127
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction) +131
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths) +223
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__1() +14
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +415
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetMetadataWorkspace>b__4() +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.LoadAndCheckItemCollection(Func`1 itemCollectionLoader) +16
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.<>c__DisplayClass16.<.ctor>b__f() +21
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +415
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +152
   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() +75
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, Boolean required) +92
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace) +12
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InitializeMappingViewCacheFactory(DbContext owner) +46
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory) +571
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() +65
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() +20
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +465
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +49
   Budzet.Controllers.HomeController.Contact() +127
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9657896
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

> **Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237